# Pulling out a random object of an array in a NodeList

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodelist

I have this script written

```
const termList = document.querySelectorAll('.term');
const randomNum = Math.random()*(termList.length-0)+0;
const randomTerm = termList[randomNum];
```

I want to have `randomTerm` pull out a random `<div>` out from that array that has that class. As written however `randomTerm` when run in the console simply produces `undefined`.

Do I need to have the `NodeList` array created by `termList` be exported into a non `NodeList` array?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to round the index.

Comment: `(termList.length-0)+0`  <-- ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.random()*(termList.length-0)+0`

Will give you a floating point number, something like `2.0523062186144134`.

Use `Math.floor` to round it down to the nearest integer like so:

```
const randomNum = Math.random()*(termList.length-0)+0;
const randomTerm = termList[Math.floor(randomNum)];
```

Also the `-0` and `+0` are superfluous:

```
const randomNum = Math.random() * termList.length;
const randomTerm = termList[Math.floor(randomNum)];
```

`Math.floor(Math.random() * termList.length)` works because `Math.random()` is guaranteed to return a value between `0` and **less** than `1`.

So rounding it down will never result in an index that is greater than the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const termList = document.querySelectorAll('.term');
const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*(termList.length));
const randomTerm = termList[randomNum];

console.log(randomTerm);
```

```html
<div class="term">foo</div>
<div class="term">bar</div>
<div class="term">baz</div>
<div class="term">foobar</div>
<div class="term">foobarbaz</div>
```